# Google SpeechClient API

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am trying to do some work using the Google Speech API. How can I specify the authentication keys using the Google Speech API Java library?
I am using this  method [Google Speech API credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409570/google-speech-api-credentials)

I want to convert audio file into text

Thank you

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("home/hussain/AndroidStudioProjects/NestedLogics/RouteApplication/service-account.json")));

        SpeechSettings settings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
        //SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create(settings);
        SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create(settings);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Path path = Paths.get(file_path);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);
            RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                    .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                    .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                    .build();
            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                    .setContent(audioBytes)
                    .build();

            RecognizeResponse response = speech.recognize(config,audio);
            List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();
            for (SpeechRecognitionResult result: results)
            {
                SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                Log.d("HOME", "convertAudioToSpeech: "+alternative.getTranscript());
            }
        }
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
   implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.6.1') {
       transitive = true
   }
   implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.10.0'
   implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-localization:0.5.0'
   implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:0.2.1'
   //firebase
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
   implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
   implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0' // this is use for runtime permissions
   implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.30.0-alpha'
   annotationProcessor 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.30.0-alpha'
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
 }
```

Comment: Are you using the Google Cloud SDK?

Comment: yes @ItamarKerbel

Answer (score 1):

After you [generated](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth) a JSON file with credentials, put it under *app/src/main/res/raw/credential.json* in the Android project sources. And then in the speech service creating code:

```
InputStream stream = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential);                   
SpeechSettings settings =
  SpeechSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(
    new CredentialsProvider() {
      @Override
      public Credentials getCredentials() throws IOException {
        return GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
      }
    }
  ).build();
```

Comment: i tried this but i got an error          Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/google/api/gax/rpc/ClientContext;)V in class Lcom/google/api/gax/rpc/ClientSettings$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientSettings$Builder' appears in /data/app/com.example.hussain.routeapplication-BtQ8fKEs7dp_ENQO4aatuw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechSettings$Builder.<init>(SpeechSettings.java:259)

Comment: It's hard to say just from this error message. Highly likely, it's a problem with dependencies, so check that your gradle configs look exactly like in the sample application.

Comment: Or may be you're using an outdated version of google-cloud-speech. Mine is `implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.41.0-alpha'`

Comment: Alexander.. build.gradle is up there.

Comment: @hussainabbas I recommend to change the dependency version from **0.30.0** to **0.41.0-alpha**

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with the Google Cloud SDK but from what I understand you should:

Create the project under the Google Cloud Services.

After you create the project and set up a payment method (as this service is not free) you will be able to download a private key in the form of a JSON file.

You then need to set up an environment variable name `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` on your machine to point to that file.
Then you should be ready to go.

You can read a detailed step by step how to [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

Click on the blue button and continue from there...